# How to refresh a JTable on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, abstracttablemodel

as many other persons, I want my JTable being actualized after adding rows.
Here you can see the fragments of my code.

```
ArrayList<> foundR = new ArrayList<FoundResult>();

JTable resultsTable = new JTable();
AbstractTableModel resultsModel = new FoundResultTableModel(foundR);//<- model which contains FoundResults as rows
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();

resultsTable.setModel(resultsModel);
scroller.add(resultsTable);
this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);// a big panel which contains scroller and other components
```

Then a add ActionListener that uses following method:

```
foundR.clear();
foundR.addAll( ...);//<- so the foundR ArrayList is refreshed
resultsModel.fireTableDataChanged();
resultsModel.fireTableStructureChanged();
```

rowCount of results Model shows that the model is refreshed (the number of rows differes from the previeous variant), but the table still doesn't appear. I tried to insert resultsTable.repaint() but it also dind't help.

UDP(NB) I discovered, that the problem is concentrated in this scroller Panel.

If I add the table directly to the big panel it is refreshed (but I cannot see all the results, since I cannot scroll down)

```
 this.add(resultsTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If I use a scroller, nothing is shown. Do you know why?

Comment: Show code of `FoundResultTableModel`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: What happens if you scroll to the bottom of your JTable in your program, then add the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code,

```
resultsTable.revalidate();
```

Since your model has been changed but the change in model should be notified to the table also.

Answer (score 1):

Just recreate the model and set it to your table.

```
foundR.clear();
foundR.addAll( ...);//<- so the foundR ArrayList is refreshed
AbstractTableModel resultsModel = new FoundResultTableModel(foundR);
resultsTable.setModel(resultsModel);
```

Comment: I discovered, that the problem is caused by the scroller (JScrollPane)